# Same account on 2 machines. Can't see the chacters created on other machine

Tags: dark-souls-2

Dark souls 2, same steam account on 2 different PC's. Can't see the characters created on the other machine. When I go to the other machine, it only shows characters created on that machine. Do I have to manualy copy files from one to the other?

Comment: I am not home so I can't check myself. But if you go to your Steam Library and view it in 'List View', there is a little cloud next to the game title if it uses the Steam Cloud. If that is not there, then saves are only local.

Answer (score 4):

Correct.

Each PC stores the saves locally. You can access these at C:/Users/Your_Name/App Data/Roaming/DarkSoulsII. Note that appdata may be a hidden folder.

Comment: Using `%appdata%/DarkSoulsII` as the path should work as well, and that's probably a bit easier to use.